# location option must be specified when creating a temporary table in SSIS Parallel Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parallel-data-warehouse

so i am loading data into a temp table in my data flow task and i keep getting the following error when i try to hit "Preview"
location option must be specified when creating a temporary table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came here like me searching for the answer - the location parameter should be specified while creating the temp table. Something like below should work.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA(
   yearId int NOT NULL,
   some1 varchar(50),
   stuff1 varchar(50))
WITH (LOCATION = USER_DB)
```

Source: http://binaryworld.net/blogs/how-to-create-temp-table-on-pdw-parallel-data-warehouse/